# ASP.NET MVC Enum in Session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enums

I am storing an Enum in the session:

```
Session.Add("workflowstatus", workflowstatus);
```

Later on I am trying to retrieve the Enum by doing:

```
model.SelectedWorkflowStatus = Session["workflowstatus"];
```

Which obviously doesn't work. Any idea how I can convert the `Session["workflowstatus"];` back to an Enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Session` will return the value back as `object`, you just need to cast it to the appropriate type i.e.

```
model.SelectedWorkflowStatus = (WorkflowStatusType)Session["workflowstatus"];
```